# Finding Functions with Certain Properties

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

I am trying to solve a special kind of problem where you have to find functions with certain properties. Smooth functions in particular. I am not familiar with this type of task and wanted to ask if you could show me a solution for the following exercises. Although there are already similar questions, much is taken for granted in the explanations of the solution.

(a) There is a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq f\leq1$, such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $|x| \geq 1$.

(b) There is a smooth function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq h \leq 1$, such that $h(x) = 0$, for $x \leq -1$ and $h(x) =1$ if $x \geq 1$.

(c) For each point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all $0 \leq r \leq R$ there is a smooth function $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq \varphi \leq 1$, such that $\varphi(x) = 1$ for $|x-p|\leq r$ and $\varphi(x) = 0$ for $|x-p| \geq R$.

Comment: You have an error in (a). Also, check the formulation of (b), because the function  $h$ you described cannot exist.

Comment: Sorry, must be -1 in (b). (a) should be right.

Comment: The function $e^{-1/x}$ might be handy for these exercises if you apply some transformations to it. (c) is the ultimate goal - to get a smooth function with compact support. This is used for partitions of unity - look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{-{1\over x}}$ is a very nice and inspirational function to be employed here. Consider $$g(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-{1\over x}}&,\quad x>0\\0&,\quad x\le 0\end{cases}$$This function is infinitely many times differentiable in $\Bbb R$, specially $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. A depict of this function is as follows:
[image]

Employing this function, we define

a)$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\tan^2{\pi\over 2}x}&,\quad |x|<1\\0&,\quad |x|\ge 1\end{cases}$$

[image]

b)$$h(x)=\begin{cases}1&,\quad x\ge 1\\e^{-\tan^2{\pi}x}&,\quad {1\over 2}\le x<1\\0&,\quad \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}$$
[image]
c) Let $p=0$ , $r=0.5$ , $R=1$ $$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}0&,\quad |x|_2\ge 1\\1-e^{-\tan^2{\pi}|x|_2}&,\quad {1\over 2}\le |x|_2<1\\1&,\quad \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}$$where $|\cdot|_p$ denotes p-norm. For $n=3$ we have the following sketch

[image]

Comment: What were your thought defining this?

Comment: The function $g(x)$ defined above is so smooth that all the derivatives in $x=0$ are zero (I knew this function from experience in one of my math classes when my professor gave us an example of a function that is not equal with its Taylor's series in $x=0$). The rest of the work in solving this question was some sort of change in variables to make the domain and the definition of the function as properly....

Comment: For example, for $(a)$ we know that $$\cos{\pi\over 2}x\sim x+1\quad,\quad x\text{ is very close to $-1$ from above}$$and $$\cos{\pi\over 2}x\sim 1-x\quad,\quad x\text{ is very close to $1$ from below}$$therefore $$\exp({-1\over\cos^2{\pi\over 2}x})\sim\exp(-{1\over (x+1)^2})\quad,\quad x\text{ is very close to $-1$ from above}$$ and$$\exp({-1\over\cos^2{\pi\over 2}x})\sim\exp(-{1\over (x-1)^2})\quad,\quad x\text{ is very close to $1$ from below}$$and by simplification$$\exp({-1\over\cos^2{\pi\over 2}x})=\exp(-1)\exp(-\tan^2{\pi\over 2}x)$$

Comment: Great! For the others, a little simpler and more intuitive way of capturing and finding such functinos is described in Lee's "Smooth Manifolds" in Chapter 4 (bump functions). Thank you very much anyway Mostafa.

Comment: Your welcome. Wish you luck and happiness!!